# Send Custom String with cURL in Qt C++

Tags: c++, curl

i use the `cURL` Library for send and login users to my application and server and use `POST` method in `cURL`. but i want to send custom and get input from user and send to the server and response but seem's error. my source below (the username and password is defined string):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

But this do not work. Only agree with this sample pattern:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Username=sina&Password=12781278");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: i get error message from my server !

Comment: So it sounds like you're sending the data just fine. What's the error message?

Comment: no actually i get error message from my written php codes its  mean the username or password is wrong !

Comment: Ok. so maybe your username and password are wrong

Comment: :|, no bro :) those are true